# How to update a table quickly

Tags: sqlite, servlets, prepared-statement

I have a web application (builted with a servlet and JSP pages) and the DB is `SQLITE`.

In some point I want to check the whole table and replace any records if needed.
I try to update my table by (I use `PreparedStatements`)

```
sq = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO myTable VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

All the records are 5000 and the process takes several minutes to complete... I noticed that for every record regardless if it is changed or not, the row is modified as I get always `rowsAffected = 1`

```
for(Label l:labels){
    stm.setString(1, l.getOldName());
    //etc...

    rowsAffected = stm.executeUpdate();
    System.out.println("rowsAffected = " + rowsAffected);
}
```

Is there any other more optimal way to update my table?

Answer (score 0):

The INSERT statement always adds one row. All the REPLACE clause does is to delete the old row, if there is one that conflicts.

If you want to avoid changing rows unnecessarily, you have to do a SELECT first to check the old values, then do UPDATE or INSERT or nothing as needed.

To speed up the process, put the entire loop into a single transaction.

Comment: I tried it and the `UPDATE` still returns `rowsAffected = 1` for all the records...

Comment: Sorry, the old answer would help only for missing rows.